# Value of type 'Data' has no member 'writeToURL'

Tags: ios, swift, cordova

I am converting code into swift 3 syntax

```
if !data.writeToURL(manifestFileURL, atomically: false) {
      self.didFailWithError(WebAppError.fileSystemFailure(reason: "Could not write asset manifest to: \(manifestFileURL)", underlyingError: error))
      return
}
```

but I am getting the error

**Value of type 'Data' has no member 'writeToURL'**

I have converted the code to

```
if try!data.write(to: manifestFileURL, atomically: false) {
      self.didFailWithError(WebAppError.fileSystemFailure(reason: "Could not write asset manifest to: \(manifestFileURL)", underlyingError: error))
      return
}
```

following the swift 3 syntax and current methods (https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1415134-write) but I get errors saying that **this is not the correct overload for the function**. Please, what is the correct way to write this out in swift 3. Any information that can lead me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`atomically: false` is equal to *no options*, you can omit the parameter.

So it's simply

```
do {
    try data.write(to: manifestFileURL)
} catch let error as NSError {
    self.didFailWithError(WebAppError.fileSystemFailure(reason: "Could not write asset manifest to: \(manifestFileURL)", underlyingError: error))
}
```

The catch clause handles the error.

Answer (score 2):

It has been rename to:

`try! data.write(to: manifestFileURL, options: [.atomic])`

Comment: It now says: '()' is not convertible to 'Bool'

Comment: It wont return `Bool`, now its handled by error throws, simply remove your Bool check

Comment: It now says: Extra argument 'options' in call

Answer (score 2):

Use [write(to: fileURL)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1410595-write).

```
do {
 try data.write(to: manifestFileURL)

 } catch let error as NSError {
  print(error)
  self.didFailWithError(WebAppError.fileSystemFailure(reason: "Could not write asset manifest to: \(manifestFileURL)", underlyingError: error))}

  return
}
```

Comment: static member 'atomic' cannot be used on instance of type 'NSData.WritingOtions'

Comment: Now there is no significant difference to my answer anymore ;-)

Comment: Your answer is perfect. I was missing something that's why i update it. Also i'm returning in catch :p